# Listing all Feature datasets and feature classes from single Geodatabase into CSV

Tags: arcpy, csv, esri-geodatabase, save, indentationerror

I have prepared a Python code and I got the following errors:

> "Parsing error IndentationError: expected an indented block (line 11)"

and

> "Runtime error Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
> line 10, in  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

The purpose of the code is to list all feature datasets & feature classes from a single geodatabase into CSV.

```py
import os
import csv
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "I:\J_Prashant's External HD\High Speed Rail\Task from Greg Campbell\Layers\HST_BP_GIS_Data.gdb"

datasetList = arcpy.ListDatasets('*','Feature')

for dataset in datasetList:
    arcpy.env.workspace = dataset
    fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for fc in fcList:
        print arcpy.env.workspace,fc

csv_out = open('I:\\python\\List-Feature-Class\\test2.csv', 'wb')
mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)
rows = zip(arcpy.env.workspace,fc)
mywriter.writerows(rows)
csv_out.close()
```

Comment: Try putting your gdb in a directory with no spaces in the filnames (e.g. `I:\GIS\HST_BP_GIS_Data.gdb`) and see if that works. Some ArcPy tools can't handle spaces.

Comment: I would also add never use special characters such as & - ' in your folder name as these will upset your code.

Comment: use 'r' in front of your env.workspace name or use double back-slashes the way you do with your csv_out variable to negate the escape character. It sounds like your datasetList object is still null because it isn't reading it properly from the workspace.

Comment: didn't work though...I am getting the same error

Comment: Try this in shell, see if it returns false - os.path.isdir(yourworkspace)

If you should be able to run something as simple as the example shown here - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000014000000

Try it and see.

Answer (score 15):

I think you should research/ask about writing to a CSV file separately at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) because the technique you are using to do that is pure Python rather than ArcPy.

For the remainder I think this should work (use a modification of your file geodatabase location where I have used C:\temp\test.gdb):

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\temp\test.gdb"

datasetList = arcpy.ListDatasets('*','Feature')

for dataset in datasetList:
    # arcpy.env.workspace = dataset
    arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\temp\test.gdb\{0}".format(dataset)
    fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for fc in fcList:
        print arcpy.env.workspace,fc
```

The two main issues were:

1. using back slashes in your pathname - you need to convert them to double backslashes, change them to forward slashes or simply escape them using the letter **r** like I have above
2. the single quote in your pathname will leave Python looking for the other one to close that string

Comment: This is not working for me. Lists a few feature classes then dies with "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" error. In fact i didn't find any script that works and simply spits out a list of feature classes. Either errors out or doesn't run at all (ESRI examples). Was hoping for paste and run solution while substituting a path to my gdb. Any ideas?

Comment: @JakubSisakGeoGraphics I think it needs a new question that says you are trying to implement this answer and gives details about the data items that work and those that fall over.

Comment: I Faced the same NoneType problem like Jakub Sisak GeoGraphics. There is a missing reference to the GDB. arcpy.List_Datasets() is only returning the name of the dataset not the full path. The following worked for me: for dataset in datasetList:
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/temp/test.gdb/"+dataset

Answer (score 2):

```
import arcpy
out_csv = r'C:\GIS\temp\features.csv'
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\GIS\data\Bakgrundskartor_LMV\Oversiktskartan.gdb'

with open(out_csv, 'a') as csvfile: #Open the file in append mode
    for f in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
        csvfile.write(f+'\n') #For each feature class, write name to the file, ending with a new line
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Code sample revisited below. Just move the arcpy.ListFeatureClasses out of the look and the code will run successfully.

```
datasetList = arcpy.ListDatasets('*','Feature')
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for dataset in datasetList:
    arcpy.env.workspace = dataset

    for fc in fcList:
        print arcpy.env.workspace,fc
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the path to the name of each dataset when you establish the env.workspace value:

```
import csv, arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

path_ = r"I:\J_Prashant's External HD\High Speed Rail\Task from Greg Campbell\Layers\HST_BP_GIS_Data.gdb"

env.workspace = path_

datasetList = arcpy.ListDatasets('*','Feature')

for dataset in datasetList:

arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(path_,dataset)
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcList:
    print arcpy.env.workspace,fc
```

Comment: This code looks like it would give an indentation error on the line that sets `arcpy.env.workspace`, and it seems like you have added an extra line of code and another function, making it less pythonic.